# Performance optimizations for write-heavy PostgreSQL table with indices

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a write-heavy table in my PostgreSQL database. For every read, there are about 100k writes. This table includes multiple (5-6) indices which is killing performance because these indices are updated on every write.

Is there anyway to optimize performance of a write-heavy table with indices? I've come up with a few options:

- Somehow disable index updates on every write and only run them on a timed interval (once every few hours would be fine for my use case).
- Delete the indices. Create a materialized view with the indices and refresh this MV every few hours. All reads will target the MV, not the primary table.
- Delete the indices. Take the performance hit on the reads.
- Anything else I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second and third point sound like good options. If you have few reads, you shouldn't need that many indexes. Consider partitioning: it can eliminate the need for one index, and it makes getting rid of old data easy.

Answer (score 1):

If your writes are all (or mostly) `INSERT` (not `UPDATE`) statements, and you can describe your data as "time-series data" - i.e. data about events that happen over time, you would probably benefit from the [TimescaleDB](https://www.timescale.com/) PostgreSQL extension.

Timescale uses a concept they call "hypertables" which transparently breaks up your data into smaller chunks based on time (and other factors if you set them up). Performance can be significantly better than plain PostgreSQL while still supporting all PostgreSQL features.

---

I am not associated with TimescaleDB; I'm just a satisfied user.

Comment: I'd consider plain partitioning without the overhead of the TimescaleDB extension.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Is that overhead significant enough to be cause for concern (compared to the benefits)?

Comment: @dakini What are the benefits?

Comment: Essentially a pre packaged solution, for those who don't do partitioning and tuning on a regular basis. For the specific case that one is indeed dealing with timeseries data

Comment: I agree with @LaurenzAlbe here, in my experience what makes timescaledb worthwile is getting to know the features that come as part of postgres anyway.